# Dart / flutter: a single element of List<String> causes exception when function expects String input

Tags: dart, flutter

Okay, this will be a really stupid question and I know the answer is like 1x1, but I can't seem to fathom it.

I have a function that fetches a couple of links from an online text. This works, the `List<String>` is loaded with proper values.

After this, I'll start and process these links by iterating through the items via a `for cycle`. In order to not mess up things, I use `async / await, so before the next iteration happens, the full processing of the current link is / should be ensured.

And this was working last week, but today, when I had some time to further work on my code, there seems to be something wonky. From out of nowhere, when the link should be processed, I get an exception:

```
E/flutter (11240): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (11240): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' where
E/flutter (11240):   String is from dart:core
E/flutter (11240):   List is from dart:core
E/flutter (11240):   String is from dart:core
E/flutter (11240): 
E/flutter (11240): #0      Initializer.fetchSingleDog (package:osszefogasaszanhuzokert/dogUtilities.dart)
E/flutter (11240): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11240): #1      Initializer.processLinks (package:osszefogasaszanhuzokert/dogUtilities.dart:46:13)
E/flutter (11240): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11240): #2      Initializer.main (package:osszefogasaszanhuzokert/dogUtilities.dart:252:11)
E/flutter (11240): <asynchronous suspension>
```

If I put a breakpoint and use debug mode, however, the first link is processed properly (but I get the same error when the 2nd should be processed). And the values are also fetched properly.

Here is my code that controls the whole process:

```
main() async {
    await fetchLinks();
    await processLinks();
  }

fetchLinks() async {
    myList = await fetchDogList();
  }

  processLinks() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
      await fetchSingleDog(myList[i]);
    }
  }

  fetchSingleDog(var link) async{

    final response = await http.get(link);
    var document = parse(response.body);

    ///Parse class elements
    name = await processClassElement(document, labelFetchName);
    type = await processClassElement(document, labelFetchBreed);
    age = await processClassElement(document, labelFetchAge);
    color = await processClassElement(document, labelFetchColor);
    gender = await processClassElement(document, labelFetchGender);

    ///Parse container elements
    description = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchDescription);
    chip = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchChip);
    neutered = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchNeutered);
    humanBehaviour = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchHumanBehavior);
    childBehaviour = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchChildBehavior);
    petBehaviour = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchPetBehavior);
    sledgeMaleBehaviour = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchSledgeMaleBehavior);
    sledgeFemaleBehaviour = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchSledgeFemaleBehavior);
    otherDogBehaviour = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchOtherDogBehavior);
    otherBehaviour = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchOtherBehavior);
    jailBreak = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchJailbreak);
    otherThings = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchOtherThings);
    foreignAdoption = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchForeignAdoption);
    imageLinks = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchForeignAdoption);

    imageLinks = await fetchDogImageLinks(document);
  }

  processClassElement(var document, var classElement) async {
    result = document.getElementsByClassName(classElement);
    var dogInfo = result[0].nodes[1].toString();
    return dogInfo.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
  }

  processContainerElement(var document, var info) async {
    var detailsContainer =
    document.getElementById('husky_details_container_right');

    var information;

    switch (info) {
      case labelFetchDescription:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[29].nodes[0]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp('"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchChip:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[3].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchNeutered:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[5].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchHumanBehavior:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[7].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchChildBehavior:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[9].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchPetBehavior:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[11].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchSledgeMaleBehavior:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[15].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchSledgeFemaleBehavior:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[17].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchOtherDogBehavior:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchOtherBehavior:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[21].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchJailbreak:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[23].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchOtherThings:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[25].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      case labelFetchForeignAdoption:
        try {
          information = detailsContainer
              .nodes[1].nodes[19].nodes[1].nodes[27].nodes[1]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'"'), '');
        } catch (e) {
          information = noInformation;
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return information;
  }
```

So I'm not really sure why the `myLinks[i]` value causes the exception: when I use debug mode, it has a single string value (the link that should be processed). Using `myLinks[i].toString()` didn't help either...

Comment: What Flutter channel/versiin are you using? There was a change very recently that sync parts of async functions are executed sync (instead of async as it was before). I'm not sure this change actualky landed already - just a wild guess.

Comment: Which line in your code above is line 46 (referred to by the exception).

Comment: I think you should start with removing `async` from methods that don't use `await` and don't make async calls. Then you also don't need to use `await` everywhere. If you add proper return types (`void` `List<String>, `String`, `Future<String>`, ...) to all methods you should get better feedback from the analyzer.

Comment: I just found out that there was a wrong processing call at the end which threw the exception eventually: imageLinks = await processContainerElement(document, labelFetchForeignAdoption);
Now that I removed this, it works again... I'll remove the awaits though, because I just realized (by your comment) that there is no need to async at those lines, as the async is already done when the document is fetched. Thanks!